# Не обновляется Qlabel, во время работы в программе

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, qt, pyqt5

Пишу программу для считывания RFID меток, добавления их в БД и дальнейший их учет. Проблема заключается в том что про добавлении метки в программу Qlabel не обновляется и не выводить данные оборудования. Подскажите как постоянно автоматически обновлять QLabel, что бы она всегда показывала актуальную информацию?

Вот весь код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys, time
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt





database = './data/testDB.db'
textbase = './data/tags.txt'
DeviceBase = './data/DeviceList.db'
ExcelList = './data/alm_hardware.xlsx'

# database = './data/testDB.db'
# textbase = './data/tags.txt'
# DeviceBase = './data/DeviceList.db'
# ExcelList = './data/alm_hardware.xlsx'




#подключение к базе данных
try:
    sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect(DeviceBase)
    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
    print("Подключен к SQLite")
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)

def insert_varible_into_table(Inventory, Serial, Model, Owner, Location, self): #добавление данных в SQLite
    sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO DeviceList
                            (Inv, Serial, Model, Owner, Location)
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"""
    data_tuple = (Inventory, Serial, Model, Owner, Location)
    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
    sqlite_connection.commit()
    print("Переменные Python успешно вставлены в таблицу DeviceList")


def LoadDeviseList():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DeviceList")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data


cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM RFID")
RFID_list = cursor.fetchall()
DeviceList = LoadDeviseList()


def insert_varible_into_table_RFID(Inventory, RFID): #добавление данных в SQLit
    if Inventory in str(RFID_list):
        cursor.execute("""DELETE FROM RFID WHERE inv = ?""", Inventory)
        sqlite_connection.commit()
    sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO RFID
                            (Inv, RFID)
                            VALUES (?, ?);"""
    data_tuple = (Inventory, RFID)
    cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
    sqlite_connection.commit()
    print("Переменные Python успешно вставлены в таблицу RFID")

def UpdateDevices(): 
        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM DeviceList")
        excel_data_df = pd.read_excel(ExcelList, sheet_name='Page 1')
        excel_list = json.loads(excel_data_df.to_json(orient='records'))
        for item in excel_list:
            if str('DECOMISSIONED') != str(item['Fixed Asset Number']):
                insert_varible_into_table(item['Fixed Asset Number'], item['Serial number'], item['Display name'], item['Assigned to'], item['Location'])
        print('Ready')

def LoadDeviseList():
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DeviceList")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    return data



class AddNewDevice(QThread):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow, parant=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
        inv = self.mainwindow.lineEdit.text()
        rfidnum = (self.mainwindow.RFID_Label.text()).partition(';')[0]
        insert_varible_into_table_RFID(inv, rfidnum)

test_rfid = ''



class ProgressBarThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow, parant=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
    def run(self):
        global test_rfid
        current_rfid = ''
        while True:
            self.mainwindow.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
            with open(textbase) as file:
                RFID_original = file.readlines()[-1]
                RFID = RFID_original.partition(';')[0]
            if current_rfid != RFID:
                font = QFont("Arial", 8)

                self.mainwindow.RFID_Label.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.RFID_Label.setText(RFID_original)
                if RFID in str(RFID_list):
                    *res1, = filter(lambda x: x[1] == RFID, RFID_list)
                    res1 = np.array(res1)
                    self.mainwindow.Device_Label.setText(f"<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:20pt; font-weight:600;\">{str(res1[0][0])}</span></p></body></html>")
                    current_rfid = RFID
                    for item in DeviceList:
                        if str(res1[0][0]) == str(item[0]):
                            #self.mainwindow.BeginResetModel()
                            font = QFont("Arial", 18)

                            self.mainwindow.label_5.setFont(font)
                            self.mainwindow.label_5.setText(str(item[0]))
                            self.mainwindow.label_5.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                            self.mainwindow.label_3.setFont(font)
                            self.mainwindow.label_3.setText(str(item[1]))
                            self.mainwindow.label_3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                            self.mainwindow.label_7.setFont(font)
                            self.mainwindow.label_7.setText(str(item[2]))
                            self.mainwindow.label_7.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                            self.mainwindow.label_10.setFont(font)
                            self.mainwindow.label_10.setText(str(item[3]))
                            self.mainwindow.label_10.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                            self.mainwindow.label_11.setFont(font)
                            self.mainwindow.label_11.setText(str(item[4]))
                            self.mainwindow.label_11.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                            #self.mainwindow.endResetModel()
                else:
                    test_rfid = RFID
                    self.mainwindow.pushButton_2.setEnabled(True)
            time.sleep(1)

    def refresh(self):
        DeviceList = LoadDeviseList()
        for item in DeviceList:
            if str(item[0]) == self.mainwindow.label_5.text():
                font = QFont("Arial", 18)

                self.mainwindow.label_5.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.label_5.setText(str(item[0]))
                self.mainwindow.label_5.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                self.mainwindow.label_3.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.label_3.setText(str(item[1]))
                self.mainwindow.label_3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                self.mainwindow.label_7.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.label_7.setText(str(item[2]))
                self.mainwindow.label_7.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                self.mainwindow.label_10.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.label_10.setText(str(item[3]))
                self.mainwindow.label_10.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

                self.mainwindow.label_11.setFont(font)
                self.mainwindow.label_11.setText(str(item[4]))
                self.mainwindow.label_11.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                break


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setEnabled(True)
        Form.resize(1019, 747)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(Form.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        Form.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        Form.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1019, 747))
        Form.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(1019, 747))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(1)
        Form.setFont(font)
        Form.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        Form.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(134, 134, 134);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 530, 281, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("AcadEref")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("\n"
"border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.Device_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.Device_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 540, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Device_Label.setFont(font)
        self.Device_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Device_Label.setIndent(-1)
        self.Device_Label.setObjectName("Device_Label")
        self.RFID_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.RFID_Label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(770, 80, 201, 35))
        self.RFID_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.RFID_Label.setIndent(-1)
        self.RFID_Label.setObjectName("RFID_Label")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(Form)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 610, 611, 111))
        self.tableWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 128);")
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(4, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 3, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 4, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(120)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setMinimumSectionSize(20)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 130, 180, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("AcadEref")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(780, 250, 180, 70))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("AcadEref")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 20, 281, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("AcadEref")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(636, 602, 381, 141))
        self.label_2.setText("")
        self.label_2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(""))
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 110, 270, 61))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 110, 300, 61))
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 350, 61))
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 20, 300, 61))
        self.label_5.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 200, 250, 61))
        self.label_6.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 200, 300, 61))
        self.label_7.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 290, 250, 61))
        self.label_8.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 380, 250, 61))
        self.label_9.setStyleSheet("\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);")
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 280, 300, 61))
        self.label_10.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 370, 300, 61))
        self.label_11.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 2, 711, 471))
        self.label_12.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 100);")
        self.label_12.setText("")
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.label_12.raise_()
        self.pushButton.raise_()
        self.Device_Label.raise_()
        self.RFID_Label.raise_()
        self.tableWidget.raise_()
        self.pushButton_2.raise_()
        self.pushButton_4.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.label_2.raise_()
        self.label.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_3.raise_()
        self.label_4.raise_()
        self.label_5.raise_()
        self.label_6.raise_()
        self.label_7.raise_()
        self.label_8.raise_()
        self.label_9.raise_()
        self.label_10.raise_()
        self.label_11.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Запустить"))
        self.Device_Label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:18pt;\">60010002288</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.RFID_Label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:9pt;\">60010002959</span></p></body></html>"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Инвентарный номер"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Серийный номер"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Модель"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Владелец"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(4)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Расположение"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "60010003856"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "PF3ETWH7"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "LENOVO ThinkPad T14 Gen 2 (Intel)"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Aleksandr Dorfman (Aleksandr.Dorfman@ru.nestle.com) "))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 4)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "FACTORY"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Обновить данные"))
        self.lineEdit.setText(_translate("Form", "1254672523"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">Serial number:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt;\">V206BB22</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">Inventory number:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt;\">60010002288</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">Model:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt;\">desktop</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">Owner:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">Location:</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt;\"Иван Иванович</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("Form", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt;\">Склад</span></p></body></html>"))



    
    
        def UpdateList():
             n = 0
             for i in DeviceList:
                 self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(DeviceList))
                 p = 0
                 for j in i:
                     self.tableWidget.setItem(n, p, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(j)))
                     p += 1
                 n += 1
        UpdateList()
        

        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "Обновить данные"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.launch_progress_bar_filling)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(lambda: (UpdateDevices(), UpdateList()))
        #self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: insert_varible_into_table_RFID(self.lineEdit.text(), (self.RFID_Label.text()).partition(';')[0]))
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(lambda: insert_varible_into_table_RFID(self.lineEdit.text(), test_rfid))
        self.ProgressbarThread_instance = ProgressBarThread(mainwindow=self)
        
       
    def launch_progress_bar_filling(self):
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.ProgressbarThread_instance.start()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

cursor.close()
if sqlite_connection:
    sqlite_connection.close()
    print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Эта программа работает совместно с другой которая как раз таки и сканирует RFID метки.

Comment: f10master, Вам практический не возможно что-то рекомендовать и вот почему. 
1.Пример, который предоставлен, не является ни минимальным, ни воспроизводимым.
2.Вы плохо рассказали, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.
3.Из визиального просмотра вашего примера видны действия, которые 
нельзя делать в PyQt: 
- НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный Qt Designer, НИКОГДА. 
Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, 
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения. >>

Comment: >> - НЕЛЬЗЯ взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительном потоке. 
Сигналы и слоты используются для связи между объектами. 
Механизм сигналов и слотов - центральная особенность Qt и, вероятно, 
часть, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками. 
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Comment: S.Nick, что вам не понятного в вопросе "Подскажите как постоянно автоматически обновлять QLabel, что бы она всегда показывала актуальную информацию?"  Я вам расшифрую.
Я хочу что бы при сканировании метки RFID, информация искалась/добавлялась в БД , а после информация об оборудовании берется из других источников и подгружается в БД, и эта же информация которая подтянулась должна отображаться в QLabel.

Comment: Темой диссертации я бы назначил - "Влияние RFID меток на обновление QLabel".